# HTML Reload PAGE - Open a article or going to other category

Tags: php, html

I using this https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/add-html App with cloudflare.
This is good because i dont need change the website script and there is some good options too
but if use google ads on it so after you changing the category on the website or go to another arcticle or something else google ads dont show...
u need to reload the page..

how i can make that after going somewhere from the website that ads will shown

please no automatic reload

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you show us your code?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried some HTML rendering things and sometimes they do not run js unless you have a delay. I assume you are putting the google ads script inside of the Add Html App

```html
<div id='container'><!-- THIS IS WHERE THE ADD WILL BE --></div>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById('container');
setTimeout(function() {
  container.innerHTML += 'PUT_AD_SCRIPT_HERE';
}, 200);
</script>
```

If the Add HTML app does not run js, this solution will not work. But since they work after you reload, I think this solution will work.

Comment: This not the best solution. It is much easier to wrap the it into a function and there is no need for setTimeout.  e.g. (function() {
   // your code
})();

Comment: can u make an e.g. code im a noob in coding =(